# restore error on sql server 2005

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql

open SQL Server Management Studio 
created one new database which is "house"(db name).
Right click on this Databases node | All Tasks | Restore database. 
Click radio button 'From database'. 
Then i go to options and select overwrite the existing database and gave the correct mdf and log file on 'restoring as' column.
 Click 'Ok'
I get the following error...... Please help me immediately

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Cannot open backup device 'D:\Program Files\MicrosoftSQLServer(Exp)\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Backup\test1.bak'. Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.). (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do direct backup/restore from database to other database with MS SQL Server...

Then you select "From database" in database restore options it doesn't mean what selected database will be used as source for restoration. In this case SQL Server Management studio perform a query among the msdb (backup history) to find databases that have been backed up. And last backup file of database selected (D:\Program Files\MicrosoftSQLServer(Exp)\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Backup\test1.bak in your case) will be used as restore source.

Comment: how to restore one database to another one database using by 'From Data base' option on sql server 2005

Comment: Omg... 1) Backup OLD database to file (e.g. D:\Program Files\MicrosoftSQLServer(Exp)\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Backup\test1.bak) 2) Try restore with "From database" option again.